type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<bool>' in flutter
    group('localTodos', () {
          final List<TodoModel> todos = [
            const TodoModel(id: 1, title: "Test Todo 1", completed: false, userId: 1),
            const TodoModel(id: 2, title: "Test Todo 2", completed: true, userId: 1),
          ];
    
          test('should call SharedPreferences to save the data', () async {
            final expectedJsonString = json.encode(todos.map((todo) => todo.toJson()).toList());
    
            print('Test setup complete');
            when(mockSharedPreferences.setString(prefKey, expectedJsonString)).thenAnswer((_) async => true);
    
            await localDataSource.localTodos(todos);
    
            print('After localTodos method call');
    
            // Ensure we verify setString was called once
            verify(mockSharedPreferences.setString(prefKey, expectedJsonString)).called(1);
          });
        });

     @override
  Future<List<TodoModel>> getLocalTodos() async {
    final jsonString = sharedPreferences.getString('SAVED_TODOS');
    if (jsonString != null) {
      List decodedJson = json.decode(jsonString);
      return decodedJson.map<TodoModel>((json) => TodoModel.fromJson(json)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('No saved todos found');
    }
  }

@override
  Future<void> localTodos(List<TodoModel> todos) async {
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> todoList = todos.map((todo) => todo.toJson()).toList();
    await sharedPreferences.setString('SAVED_TODOS', json.encode(todoList));
  }

Was writing a test for a todo app with sharedpref, ijust added the code for the datasource. There are other tests like one for getting all saved todos and it runs fine, my problem lies with this test

Try to declare your mockSharedPreferences & prefKey inside group

Please post a minimal reproducible example.  Did you follow Mockito's code-generation steps?

no there is no code generation happening, i followed the documentation guidelines and the other tests are working fine except this one

@EdKluivert You must perform code generation to use Mockito properly (or to do a lot of work yourself).  This is explained by the Mockito instructions.
